# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'AddressLine'

Tags: python, django, django-models

**I have:**

*Models:*

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # Họ Và Tên
    UserFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserMiddleName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserLastName = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[name_regex])
    UserFullName = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    AddressIDProfile = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    AddressProfile = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Profile"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.AddressProfile = self.AddressIDProfile.AddressLine
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Problem:**
I want to assign data to the AddressProfile field by getting it from the foreign keyword AddressIDProfile. But when AddressLine is None, an error occurs. I tried to test it first but with no success. Please give me the solution.Thanks!!!

Comment: "But when AddressLine is None, an error occurs." Okay, *what do you want to happen* when this is the case? "I tried to test it first but with no success." Okay, *how did you try*?

Comment: I hope, if AddressLine is None then it will pass and not execute this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to catch the `AttributeError` not `ObjectDoesNotExist`. or check the `self.AddressIDProfile` before retrieve `AddressLine`.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.AddressProfile = self.AddressIDProfile.AddressLine
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

or

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.AddressIDProfile:
        self.AddressProfile = self.AddressIDProfile.AddressLine
    else:
        pass
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```